# Pin to top of screen in iPad compatibility mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, compatibility

I have an application where I want to pin something to the very top of the screen. When running in iPad compatibility mode, the top of the item is getting chopped off.

Is there an obvious way to pin to the top of the visible screen other than detecting that I'm in compatibility mode and moving the top item down by 20 pixels?